# Ошибка при обновлении страницы (404), путь к которой через / (React JS Роутинг)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Настроила в приложении роутинг, но если я с главной страницы перехожу на другие, при обновлении все падает с ошибкой 404. При этом когда я разворачиваю проект локально, страницы обновляются, все работает. Залила код на сервер, получается ошибка. Может, в настройках сервера надо что-то изменить?

Comment: Вы уверены, что локально у вас работает роутинг? Хостинг тут врят ли как то влияет, т.к. реактовский роут работает на клиенте, а 404 ошибка говорит о том, что поше запрос на сервер

Comment: это не ошибка, а дефолтное поведение. Без бекенда кроме главной остальные страницы не будут работать. Локально этой проблемы нет лишь благодаря webpack. Чтобы решить можно использовать HashRouter из react-router-dom или настроить формирование страниц и на сервере.

Comment: @Arbery спасибо! А можете ресурсом каким-то поделиться, как это на сервере настроить, если с hash router не получится? Настройкой сервера не занималась никогда, пока не нашла, где о таком почитать

Comment: @Arbery хотя, спасибо, HashRouter помог!) С настройкой сервера тоже нашла решение